# Appending invisible ASCII characters to string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to add an invisible character (`CAN` - ASCII Code 24) to a `str`, but it only adds the ASCII code of that character (obviously because I am using `str(24)`).

Is there some way to add the character 24 to a string object?

Comment: `str()` converts the integer to a string representation.. Where you looking for `chr()` perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) to get the character corresponding to an ASCII ordinal value.

```
myString += chr(24)
```